# Bullets follows mouse position

Tags: javascript, html

Im making simple arena shooter in JS and HTML.

right now I wanted to add shooting mechanic,I thought i would use code from my enemy  class with bits of tweaking

here:

```
//differences between objects
let dirx = mouse.x - player.x,  
diry = mouse.y - player.y; 
//normalizing
let dist = Math.sqrt(dirx * dirx + diry * diry);

dirx = dirx / dist;
diry = diry / dist;

this.x += dirx * 5; 
this.y += diry * 5;
```

Since my player is moving the player.x& player.y coords in dirX & dirY will change, meaning bullet wont go to original coords.

So I would be pleased for some help.

Comment: Upon bullet creation you could just store the player location as `targetX` and `targetY` then each update cycle use those coordinates instead of the player location

Comment: I would use vectors to track positioning. Check out [victor.js](http://victorjs.org).

Comment: The bullet should have it's own magnitude and direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vectors to determine the trajectory of the bullets.

In the example below, when I fire a bullet:

- Initialize the position at the source of the bullet
- The speed is determined by:

  - Subtracting the mouse position from the source
  - Normalizing the distance
  - Applying a speed constant

```js
class Bullet {
  constructor(source, target, created) {
    this.position = source.clone();
    this.speed = this.position.clone()
      .subtract(Victor.fromObject(target))
      .normalize()
      .multiply(new Victor(-2, -2));
    this.size = 3;
    this.timeLeft = created + 500;
  }
  update() {
    this.position = this.position.add(this.speed);
  }
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

**Note:** I also added a `timeLeft` variable to remove the bullet from the game after a set period of time e.g. 500ms.

---

### Demo

Here is an example using the vector logic explained above.

#### Controls

- <kbd>W</kbd> (Up) - Move up
- <kbd>A</kbd> (Left) - Move left
- <kbd>S</kbd> (Down) - Move down
- <kbd>D</kbd> (Right) - Move right
- <kbd>Mouse 1</kbd> - Hold to fire

```js
const VK_W = 87;
const VK_A = 65;
const VK_S = 83;
const VK_D = 68;
const VK_UP = 38;
const VK_DOWN = 40;
const VK_LEFT = 37;
const VK_RIGHT = 39;

const canvas = document.querySelector('.game'),
  stateBtn = document.querySelector('.state-btn');

let game;

const main = () => {
  stateBtn.addEventListener('click', changeState);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  game = new Game(ctx, { width: 400, height: 300 });
  game.run();
};

const changeState = (e) => {
  const btn = e.currentTarget, running = btn.dataset.running === 'true';
  if (running) {
    game.pause();
  } else {
    game.run();
  }
  
  btn.textContent = running ? 'Pause' : 'Resume';
  btn.dataset.running = !running;
};

class Game {
  constructor(ctx, options) {
    const { width, height } = options;
    this.lastRender = 0;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.state = { keySet: new Set() };
    this.bullets = [];
    Object.assign(ctx.canvas, { width, height });
    const origin = new Victor(width / 2, height / 2);
    this.player = new Player({
      name: 'Bob',
      position: origin
    });
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => this.followMouse(e));
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.mouseDown(e));
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => this.mouseUp(e));
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => this.addKey(e), false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this.removeKey(e), false);
  }
  followMouse(e) {
    this.state.mousePos = getMousePos(e.currentTarget, e);
  }
  mouseDown(e) {
    this.state.mouseDown = true;
  }
  mouseUp(e) {
    this.state.mouseDown = false;
  }
  addKey(e) {
    const key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
    this.state.keySet.add(key);
  }
  removeKey(e) {
    const key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
    this.state.keySet.delete(key);
  }
  update(progress) {
    const ks = this.state.keySet;
    const x = (ks.has(VK_D) || ks.has(VK_RIGHT))
      ? 1   : (ks.has(VK_A) || ks.has(VK_LEFT)) ? -1 : 0;
    const y = (ks.has(VK_S) || ks.has(VK_DOWN))
      ? 1   : (ks.has(VK_W) || ks.has(VK_UP))   ? -1 : 0;
    this.player.position.add(new Victor(x, y));
    this.bullets.forEach((bullet, index) => {
      if (this.lastRender > bullet.timeLeft) {
        this.bullets.splice(index, 1);
      }
      bullet.update(this.lastRender);
    });
    if (this.state.mousePos && this.state.mouseDown) {
      this.bullets.push(new Bullet(this.player.position,
        this.state.mousePos, this.lastRender));
    }
  }
  draw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.width, this.ctx.canvas.height);
    this.player.draw(this.ctx);
    this.bullets.forEach(bullet => bullet.draw(this.ctx));
  }
  run(timestamp) {
    const progress = timestamp - this.lastRender;
    this.update(progress);
    this.draw();
    this.lastRender = timestamp;
    this.req = window.requestAnimationFrame((t) => this.run(t));
  }
  pause() {
    const { width, height } = this.ctx.canvas;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    this.ctx.font = '32px Arial';
    this.ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
    this.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    this.ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    this.ctx.fillText('Paused', width / 2, height / 2);
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.req);
    this.req = null;
  }
  isRunning() {
    return this.req !== null;
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor(options) {
    const opts = { ...Player.defaultOptions, ...options };
    this.name = opts.name;
    this.position = opts.position;
    this.size = opts.size;
  }
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
    ctx.fillRect(this.position.x - this.size / 2,
      this.position.y - this.size / 2, this.size, this.size);
  }
};

Player.defaultOptions = {
  size: 10,
  position: new Victor(0, 0)
};

class Bullet {
  constructor(source, target, created) {
    this.position = source.clone();
    this.speed = this.position.clone()
      .subtract(Victor.fromObject(target))
      .normalize()
      .multiply(new Victor(-2, -2));
    this.size = 3;
    this.timeLeft = created + 500;
  }
  update() {
    this.position = this.position.add(this.speed);
  }
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

const getMousePos = (canvas, event) =>
  (({ top, left }) => ({
    x: event.clientX - left,
    y: event.clientY - top
  }))(canvas.getBoundingClientRect());

main();
```

```css
.game {
  background: #111;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4em !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/victor/1.1.0/victor.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="game"></canvas>
<div class="controls">
  <button class="state-btn" data-running="true">Pause</button>
</div>
```